# Getting error "the provided uri scheme 'https' is invalid expected 'http" from service

Tags: rest, web-services, wcf, soap, basichttpbinding

I'm getting this error. Do you have any idea?

My code is below;

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="Integration" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://test/WcfService/Integration.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Integration"
        contract="IntegrationService.Integration" name="Integration" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may modify your app.config as shown in the following example:

```
<bindings> 
<basicHttpBinding> 
<binding name="Integration"> 
  <security mode="Transport"> 
    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/> 
    <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" algorithmSuite="Default" />
  </security> 
</binding> 
</basicHttpBinding> 
</bindings>
```